# Could this do-monad be replaced by a let block?

Tags: clojure, monads, let

The [author here provides](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/08/quick-reference-monads-and-testcheck.html) the following example usage of a do-monad to combine test generators:

```
(require '[clojure.test.check.generators :as gen])
(require '[clojure.algo.monads :as m])
(m/defmonad gen-m 
  [m-bind gen/bind 
   m-result gen/return])

(def vector-and-elem
  (m/domonad gen-m
    [n (gen/choose 1 10)
     v (gen/vector gen/int n)
     e (gen/element v)]
    [v, e]))

(gen/sample vector-and-elem)
    ([[0 -1 1 0 -1 0 -1 1] 0] 
    [[1 1 3 3 3 -1 0 -2 2] 3]
    [[8 4] 8]...
```

There [commentator here asserts](https://twitter.com/noidi/status/574217292860497921) that this is a great example of monads not just for their own sake, but for providing a genuine value-add.

To me this doesn't seem that different from what a let-block is doing. Indeed - [Brian Marick](http://www.exampler.com/) [here compares the](https://vimeo.com/20717301) do-monad to a let block.

My question is: **Could this do-monad be replaced by a let block?**

Comment: The function is called [`elements`](http://clojure.github.io/test.check/clojure.test.check.generators.html#var-elements) not `element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of `test.check` the answer is **no**, this `do-monad` can't be replaced by a `let` block. But you can use the `gen/bind` and `gen/return` manually like this:

```
(def vector-and-elem
  (gen/bind (gen/choose 1 10)
            (fn [n]
              (gen/bind (gen/vector gen/int n)
                        (fn [v]
                          (gen/bind (gen/elements v)
                                    (fn [e]
                                      (gen/return [v e]))))))))
```

This is what the `Monad` is doing under the covers for you.

Trying to write this as a `let`:

```
(def vector-and-elem-let
  (let [n (gen/choose 1 10)
        v (gen/vector gen/int n)
        e (gen/elements v)]
    [v e]))
```

Doesn't work because the functions: `choose`, `vector`, and `elements` returns a *generator* not the result of the *generator*. So for example `gen/vector` expects a `Integer` as the second argument not a `generator` and this `let` doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

As of test.check `0.9.0` there is a macro `gen/let` that supports this sort of thing.