# test.check: let-style behaviour in 'properties/for-all'

Tags: clojure, monads, test.check

Following on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28961373/3166303), and the blog [post](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/08/quick-reference-monads-and-testcheck.html) referenced there, is there a reason why `prop/for-all` does not just roll in this sort of capability directly? E.g. something like:

```
(require '[clojure.test.check.generators :as gen])
(require '[clojure.test.check.properties :as prop])
(require '[clojure.test.check.clojure-test :refer :all])

(defspec some-props-test
  (prop/for-all [n (gen/choose 1 10)
                 v (gen/vector gen/int n) ;; treat n like its produced value
                 e (gen/element v)]
    ... do stuff with n, v & e ...
  ))
```

Basically, I want to re-use the **value produced** by one generator in another generator and then reference **both** values produced within the actual test code. This would essentially extend the sugar/magic of `for-all` into allowing references to the generated values within the let-like block provided by the macro, as it works within the expression blocks below.

Please let me know if I'm missing something else that makes this possible or it just wouldn't make sense for some reason to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that this functionality would probably be more useful than what `for-all` currently does. The primary reason it hasn't been changed is for backwards-compatibility (though admittedly code using the old style wouldn't break, it would just not shrink as well as it used to).

But you have more options available than just monads:

- `gen/let`, which uses `let`-style bindings (it isn't a drop-in replacement for `for-all` but you can use them together)
- `com.gfredericks.test.chuck.generators/for` defined in the [test.chuck](https://github.com/gfredericks/test.chuck) helper library — it's like a fancier version of `gen/let`
- `com.gfredericks.test.chuck.properties/for-all`, in the same library, which *is* a drop-in replacement for `for-all`

Comment: great, `gen/let` replaces this nicely. I'll definitely check out `test.chuck` as well though. As a side note - I noticed the API docs link on the main `test.check` github page still points to `0.8.2`, the version before the introduction of `let`.

Comment: yeah, I have a TODO to update the API docs; last time I tried there was a confusing problem with the docs library, with no easy solution. Thanks for the reminder – it's useful to know it matters to somebody.

Comment: Np, thanks for all your hard work on the fantastic library!

Comment: tried out the `for-all` in `test.chuck` and it does exactly what I want. the way `test.check` `for-all` *should* work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found the later blog [post](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/10/a-monadically-built-generator.html) in that series which fully flushes out usage with `test.check` (needed to read up a little on `monads` first to grok it). So first the monad can be declared:

```
(require '[clojure.algo.monads :as m])

(m/defmonad gen-m
    [m-bind gen/bind
     m-result gen/return])

(def vector-and-elem
  (m/domonad gen-m
    [n (gen/choose 1 10)
     v (gen/vector gen/int n)
     e (gen/element v)]
    [n v e]))
```

The `gen-m` monad allows referencing the value that will be generated for previously declared generators.

Then, it can be used directly in the `for-all` call:

```
(defspec some-props-test
  (prop/for-all [[n v e] vector-and-elem]
    ... do stuff with n, v & e ...
  ))
```

You can just pass all the values that are relevant to your constraint-checking code in the expression produced by the `gen-m` monad call via a vector (or map if you like) and de-structure it to get what you need.

Still, it would be nice if this was done automatically in `for-all`, but this works well enough.